# WordPress вызвать хранимую процедуру после успешной оплаты paypal

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Мне нужно подключить paypal-платеж к моему сайту wordpress. Для этого я использую https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paypal/. Но после успешной оплаты мне нужно вызвать хранимую процедуру, в которой мне нужно передать несколько параметров. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в functions.php вашей темы

```
function wp_paypal_order_processed_action( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    // Здесь вызовите вашу процедуру.
}
add_action( 'wp_paypal_order_processed', 'wp_paypal_order_processed_action' );
```

Comment: Правильно если я так вызову функцию? $wpdb->query("CALL ExtendLicense('someEmail@gmail.com', 30, 30, 1)");

Comment: Ну вызов-то такой, а что внутри вашего вызова (CALL...)- я не знаю и не могу сказать, будет ли это работать. Я даю гарантию лишь того, что мой код сработает после успешной оплаты - я проанализировал код вашего плагина и увидел, что он вызывает действие `wp_paypal_order_processed`.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен если сможет помочь

Comment: Я вряд ли смогу помочь по процедуре, советую сформулировать отдеьный вопрос, при этом описать структуру таблицы базы данных, с которой работает эта процедура.

Comment: В вашем комментарии не вижу add_action, сравните с моим ответом

Comment: Не скопировал просто. Процедура точно рабочая, проверялась. Мне кажется я неправильно ее вызываю том, что ни делается запись в базу ((

Comment: да нет, вызов правильный https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb А, ну так надо еще написать global $wpdb; Добавил в ответ